# Invalid method Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::canBeFilterableInGrid when accesing customer_grid in the administration

Tags: magento2, customer, grid

This error is pretty strange, how come that when I try to access the customer grid all of the sudden it is throwing me this error?

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::canBeFilterableInGrid
```

I checked that class and the method does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

After having this exception myself and losing my mind over what the problem was I figured it was something to do with my database rather than the Magento code base.

Based upon the exception, it probably meant that one of my attributes was using the wrong model.

`1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::canBeFilterableInGrid`

I went into the **`eav_attribute`** table and saw that the attribute: **`disable_auto_group_change`** had the attribute_model of **`Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute`**.

After removing this, all worked and the customer grid loaded again.

Obviously, this thread is old, but I hope this helps anyone experiencing the same issue, as there is little to no solutions for it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error recently in one of my Magento projects, below is the error screenshot.

[image: Error screenshot]

Then I've got a solution that is replacing a part of the code in a file

```
vendor/magento/module-rule/Model/Condition/Product/AbstractProduct.php

if (!$attribute->isAllowedForRuleCondition() || !$attribute->getDataUsingMethod($this->_isUsedForRuleProperty))
```

with

```
if (!$attribute->getDataUsingMethod($this->_isUsedForRuleProperty) ||!$attribute->isAllowedForRuleCondition())
```

Below is a screenshot of the code file

[image: Error replace screenshot]